# How to transform from a SRID to another?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

How can I transform a geometric column of table from "SRID=4326" to "SRID=32650".
I saw "ST_Transfom" and " ST_SETSRID" operator before. To do so, I used follow construction operator, But it dosen't work. Any suggestion please?

```
select ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom_line , 32650), 32650)
from my_Table;
```

Answer (score 4):

ST_SetSRID part of your query is breaking it. Using set SRID sets the SRID to 32650 without transforming it. So you are setting the SRID to 32650, and then trying to convert it to 32650, but it is already 32650 because you set it as so.

So try:

```
select ST_Transform(geom_line , 32650)
from my_Table;
```

If this does not work your data may not have a SRID to begin with:

```
select ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom_line, 4326), 32650)
from my_Table;
```

Comment: TNX for your replay. I use " UpdateGeometrySRID" and "ST_SETSRID" operator, but it dosen't work yet ;(

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: In PGAdmin, what does the SQL pane have as the type for geom_line? It should look something like: geom_line geometry(Geometry,32650)